# How to extract values from data.frame conditionally?

Tags: r

I am a newbie who started learning R just recently. This may be a very basic question, but it gives me headache for two hours. Please help.

The question is:

when Data1 = iris,
Remove those observations whose Sepal.Width is greater than or equal to 2 times
its Petal.Length and put the remaining observations into a new object Data2. Export Data2 as a file called newData.txt without the names of rows but with the names of each variable. You only need to show the commands for exporting the data.

Also, because I am stuck there, I cannot precede to the next question which:

Import the data from the file newData.txt into a new object Data3 ; Data3
should be the same as Data2. Report the (i) number of observations in Data3, (ii) number of species versicolor in Data3.

Please help. Thank you guys.

Comment: Search SO with term "subset"

Comment: Oh my thank God!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! it was so simple. Is it close? > Data2 = subset.data.frame(Data1, Data1$Sepal.Width>=2*Data1$Petal.Length)

Comment: Don't put "Data1$" before the column names in  "subset"-expressions. And remember that "!" before a logical expression gives the logical complement.

Comment: Could you tell me why not to put Data1$ before the column names? It seems there is no difference whether or not it is there. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "!" in this problem. Isn't ! expressing the meaning of not-identicality?

Comment: When you just use the col names subset looks them up in the first argument. It's the "right way".

Answer (score 0):

Definitely worth learning the basics of $, !, and [], but dplyr is also a helpful package for data manipulation.  Type `vignette()` for some helpful examples, `vignette('name')` when you find one that seems interesting.

I would also recommend [www.rstudio.com](http://www.rstudio.com) as an IDE if you are still using R GUI.

As to your question, using dplyr:

```
require(dplyr)

data1 <- as.tbl(iris)
data2 <- iris %>% filter(!(Sepal.Width >= 2 * Petal.Length))

write.table(data2, file='newData.txt',row.names=FALSE)
data3 <- read.table('newData.txt',header=TRUE, sep=' ')

identical(data2,data3)

data3 %>% summarize(nobs=n(), speciesversicolor=n_distinct(Species))
```